# Android accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

Is there any application that is available which I can try out to see the difference between using an accelerometer and gyroscope (where the lag is evident while using an accelerometer). I get the theoretical aspect of using a gyroscope over an accelerometer. But I would like to see it visually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not an app but in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k&feature=player_detailpage#t=1315s), starting from 21:55, there is a demo.